# MySQL how to take data from one column and put to another column under same ID and same table

Tags: mysql, insert

I have table PRODUCTS with 3 columns

```
id   merchant   selected (empty column)
1    Roger
2    Anthony
3    Maria
4    Joseph
5    Serge
```

I want to make query something like this (syntax is wrong, just an idea to explain what I try to do)

```
SELECT * WHERE merchant LIKE '%thon%' FROM products.merchant 
INSERT INTO products.selected
```

but to place to the same ID row, so a result should be like this

```
id   merchant   selected
1    Roger
2    Anthony    Anthony
3    Maria
4    Joseph
5    Serge
```

Would be very obliged for a hint how to make such a trick !

Answer (score 2):

The query of @Kickstart and @daghan is correct:

```
UPDATE products
SET selected = merchant
WHERE merchant LIKE '%thon%'
```

But I have a suggestion about the structure of your table,if you want to make on of the row selected, you can change the type of select column to **TINYINT** or **BOOLEAN** and then your table will be something like this:

```
id   merchant   selected
1    Roger
2    Anthony    1
3    Maria
4    Joseph
5    Serge
```

this will help you to write easier query, and final query will be STH like this :

```
UPDATE products
SET selected = 1
WHERE merchant LIKE '%thon%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple update, if I am reading your requirement correctly:-

```
UPDATE products
SET selected = merchant
WHERE merchant LIKE '%thon%'
```

Comment: Thank you, but how it will copy to column 'selected' under same ID ?

Comment: I do not understand what it is you need. Your example output shows the row for that id being updated

Comment: `UPDATE` works on a row by row basis.  You can use the values of other columns in the same row as Kickstart's answer shows.

Comment: Can it be made with a SUBSTRING query ? I mean extract a part of text from one column using SELECT SUBSTRING - and put a result to empty column under same ID ?

Comment: yes, it's possible,look at here:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-string-functions.htm

Comment: this is an example:

SELECT LastName, SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1, 1) AS Initial
FROM Person.Person
WHERE LastName like 'Barl%'

Comment: Dear Reza, if we use my simplest example above - let's say we can use SELECT SUBSTRING(merchant,1,1) - but how to combine it together with UPDATE products SET selected = merchant - to put extracted text to column SELECTED against same ID ?

Comment: Following on from @RezaM.A helpful comments, you can use a substring in an update easily. For example to set selected to be the 4 characters fro the merchant name for matching rows - _UPDATE products SET selected = SUBSTRING(merchant,1,4) WHERE merchant LIKE '%thon%'_

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET selected = merchant WHERE merchant LIKE '%thon%'
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! May you add an idea how to do that using SELECT SUBSTRING ? Please, see my comment above.

Comment: Honestly, it is not clear why u want to do that by SELECT SUBSTRING? What is your exact purpose? (PS: a short and good sql tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql  -> might be helpful)